# Equals vs. Is when dealing with GetType()

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here's the scenario,

I have a silverlight C1 Datacolumn, and I want to check its type.

I know of two ways to do so:

```
 SilverLightColumn.DataType.Equals(GetType(Decimal))
```

And

```
 SilverLightColumn.DataType Is GetType(String)
```

The .DataType is a System.Type.

Is one way better than the other, or are they equivalent?

Or, am I totally wrong and there exists a better way to check for the type?

Comment: Depends what you want to accomplish.  As posted, neither makes a difference since both Decimal and String are sealed types so there isn't any risk that the Is operator is going to like a type you don't like.  Stick with Equals until you find a compelling reason to use Is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent. If you had the following

```
Class Foo
   '...
End Class

Class Bar Inherits Foo
   '...
End Class
```

And the type of `DataType` is the type for `Bar` then

```
SilverLightColumn.DataType Is GetType(Foo)
```

will return true, however

```
SilverLightColumn.DataType.Equals(GetType(Foo))
```

will return false. `Is` will return true for that type or any type that inherits from it, `Equals` must be the exact same type.

Answer (score 0):

```
SilverLightColumn.DataType Is GetType(String)
```

`Is` will allow any type that inherits fronm it

```
SilverLightColumn.DataType = GetType(String)
```

`=` Allows only the exact match

You can also use the `TypeOf` operator instead of the `GetType` method